# WCF Service not working in IIS after Web app migration

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-8

I migrated my web app hosting a WCF Service from Windows 10 to Windows Server 2012. I followed the steps below:

- Copied the folder where the Web App's files are to the new machine.
- Installed all ASP.NET and WCF features.
- Created a new application targeting the folder containing the files of the application.

When I try to run the service I get

`HTTP 404 Error, The Resource cannot be found.`

When I just target the svc file I get

`Metadata publishing for this service is currently disabled.`

I don't get this message when hitting the same URL in the original machine. Instead I get the regular screen telling me that I have created a service.

When hitting the root folder on a browser, in the original machine I get a white screen but in the new machine I get

`A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.`

As far as I can say, all configuration parameters are the same in both machines.

I want to add a detail that might help. When I restart the site on the original machine, the first time I request the service, I wait a few seconds for the site to compile and run. On the new machine this doesn't seem to happen. It may be that the code-behind is not loaded at all.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if your IIS has svc handler added.

WCF services don’t run on IIS with the default configuration, because the webserver doesn’t know, how to handle incoming requests targeting .svc files. You can teach it in two steps:

1. Add a new MIME type:

`Extension: .svc 
MIME type: application/octet-stream`

[image]

2. Add a new Managed HTTP Handler:

   `Request path: *.svc 
   Type: System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpHandler 
   Name: svc-Integrated`

[image]

Refresh your website/web application

References:

http://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/publishing-a-wcf-service-on-iis8/

http://proq.blogspot.hk/2012/09/wcf-on-iis-and-windows-8.html

http://forums.iis.net/t/1200413.aspx?+svc+missing+can+t+find+Module+to+load+within+Handler+Mapping+IIS+8+0

Answer (score 0):

Enable FTP Server from Control Panel->Programs and Features
http://www.kebabshopblues.co.uk/2013/09/20/hosting-a-wcf-service-library-project-in-iis-8-0-windows-8-0-net-4-5/

> From **Control Panel|Programs and Features**, enable the following:
>   **Internet Information Services** (a number of contained items will be selected automatically, but not all, most notably the **FTP Server**);
>   ‘HTTP Activation’ under ‘.Net Framework 4.5 Advanced Services | WCF
>   Services’  (there is a fairly similar option ‘Windows Communication
>   Foundation HTTP Activation’ under the ‘.Net Framework 3.5 (includes
>   .NET 2.0 and 3.0’ which I guess would be necessary if you were
>   targeting an earlier version of .Net);

Answer (score 0):

There may be some features that support WCF that are not yet enabled in IIS. I have followed your steps to deploy the existed WCF service and consume the service successfully. Here are my features I have enabled in IIS.
[image]
Result.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.